# Call Threads in Order (Cracking the Coding Interview)

Tags: java, multithreading

In the Threads and Locks chapter of Cracking the Coding Interview (15 for the 6th edition, 16 for the 5th), the following is Question 5:

***Call In Order:*** Suppose we have the following code:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() { ... }
    public void first() { ... }
    public void second() { ... }
    public void third() { ... }
}
```

*The same instance of Foo will be passed to three different threads. `threadA` will call `first()`, `threadB` will call `second()`, and `threadC` will call `third()`. Design a mechanism to ensure that `first` is called before `second` and `second` is called before `third`.*

My understanding is that the suggested solution uses the following procedure:

- In the constructor, initialize and acquire (decrement) two binary semaphores `sem1` and `sem2`.
- In `first()`, run the procedure, then release (increment) `sem1` immediately before returning.
- In `second()`, wait to acquire `sem1` and then release it before running the procedure. Release `sem2`.
- In `third()`, wait to acquire `sem2`, release `sem2`, and run the procedure.

which is more or less what I would have done. However the solution also claims that, *"Because we need to be very careful about thread safety, simple boolean flags won't do the job."*

What correctness issue arises from simply keeping two (initially false) boolean flags `firstDone` and `secondDone` and setting these to true at the end of the corresponding method? `second()` and `third()` would simply spin on `firstDone` and `secondDone`, respectively.

I've thought about this for over an hour now, and I fail to see a (non-performance-related) issue with this strategy. In fact, the two seem near-identical to me if we treat `false` as the integer 0 and `true` as 1, in that the value of the boolean always matches the value of the corresponding semaphore at a given point in the code.

Comment: Note that if you're handling the semaphores in `first()`, `second()` and `third()`, you're not controlling which one is called first: you're just blocking them from proceeding once called.

Comment: If the booleans aren't volatile, the second thread could keep spinning forever even if the first thread has toggled the boolean.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's what I had in mind with the boolean method: the blocking would have been done by spinning (looping) on a boolean instead. For example, second would have looked like 

while !firstDone {

}
// run procedure;
secondDone = true;

where firstDone is set at the end of first().

Comment: @JBNizet I did intend to mark the booleans as volatile; sorry for not making that clear in the post. Are you suggesting that the boolean strategy would work if the booleans were volatile?

Comment: It wouldn't be efficient and could starve the first thread by eating the CPU doing nothing useful, but I don't see why it wouldn't work, no.